# Trigger an azure email alert from C# code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I need to trigger an Azure alert from C# code , based on some conditions. So I am checking certain conditions in database and if the conditions are meeting, I need to trigger the alert which will send the email to few recipients. How can I achieve that in C#

Comment: Which [azure alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-alerts) are you talking about? Or you just want to send the email via azure?

Comment: use a WebJob and TimerTrigger. Read the email in your code and send SMTP email if the conditions are met.